# Extending bookshelf model with typescript causes error

Tags: typescript, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have instantiated bookshelf like this in a configuration file:

```js
// irrelevant code omitted
const knex = Knex(knexfile[env]);

const bookshelf = Bookshelf(knex as any);

const { Model } = bookshelf;

export default Model;
export { bookshelf };
```

This works fine; all the imports resolve and exports work. I created a model like this:

```js
import Model from '../config/bookshelf';

class Module extends Model<{id:number}> {
  table = 'modules';

  get tableName() { return this.table; }
}
```

However, I get an error from TypeScript saying `Type '{ id: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Model<any>': belongsTo, belongsToMany, count, destroy, and 41 more.` It seems like TypeScript is expecting that the type I provide for Model must define all methods on the Model class that it extends from, however this appears inconsistent with [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481043/strongly-typed-database-access-with-node-js-and-typescript) and [the DefinitelyTyped example](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/bookshelf/bookshelf-tests.ts). Any thoughts on how to resolve this on my end without adding all 40-something methods to my model's type?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new class that extends `bookshelf.Model<class>`:

```
class Module extends Model<Module> {
    table = 'modules';
    public id: number = 0;

    get tableName() { return this.table; }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAaQHYFMAecBmUIjgIgGtU18BuAWAChRJY4AhCCQgZwAsUAbTLHPfACNmbTj3LUA9JLjAoUbigBuAQyTwAxhAAmKOLmAwYKbdS1JW8YujgBeRCQAU+fAEpKVc5bjCWHbrz2TH5imI7WGCqscGoAnu7UZhAW8ADecACyOtxwAL52PiL+PB7U6HTwupgqAK5c8Fm6XB7l0GmFIQF5pZ5cUdGNdXroxkjaA9lcADyDXCgAfHCp1HCrcDAqgnMFAOQgOkOsOx5rcGA1W8AastoAXHBINSCCKFAFAAw9pwDmKPAbWxQADkVCAUI5XEs4AoYDUoEh1uxgKwAHQAuZkPLUXJAA)

> Though this is rather *interresting* TypeScript Support